# What are the meanings of /proc/net/route columns? especially Flags column

Tags: android, linux, routes, linux-kernel

This is what my Android device shows:

```
$ cat route
Iface   Destination Gateway     Flags   RefCnt  Use Metric  Mask        MTU Window  IRTT                                                       
rmnet0  D532BD0A    00000000    0005    0   0   0   FFFFFFFF    0   0   0                                                                             
rmnet0  0000000A    00000000    0001    0   0   0   000000FF    0   0   0                                                                             
rmnet0  00000000    D532BD0A    0003    0   0   0   00000000    0   0   0
```

I am not familiar with the Linux kernel. After searching a lot, sadly I cannot find useful explanation. Can someone explain it? Especially for the Flags column, what's the meaning of 0001 0003 0005? It's OK to provide some reference as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flags column is a combination of the RTF_* flags. You can find them in [linux/route.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/route.h#L50)

For the other fields, have a look at [fib_route_seq_show](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/fib_trie.c#L2560)

Comment: Thanks.  I have read the route.h.  Why  RTF_* values donot  contain 0003, 0005 in the table ?

Comment: It is a combination of flags. 0x3 is 0x2 + 0x1, that is `RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY`. 0x5 is 0x4 + 0x1, that is `RTF_UP | RTF_HOST`.

Comment: Got it.  Could you explain the specific meaining for the route entry in detail ?  For example,  0x3 means  it's usable and  D532BD0A is gateway ?   And which is host in 0x5 entry?  Thanks

Comment: It means that you can use rmnet0 to contact D532BD0A (that is 10.99.32.95) directly. This indicates that you are somehow using point to point communication (I'd say pptp).

Comment: Also, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer.

Comment: The link to route.h didn't work for me, an alternative is https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/route.h